# How to convert a 2d array to 3d array dynamically in groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy

How can we convert a 2d array to 3d dynamically.I am having below input and i'm splitting using closure for 2d array but how can we convert to 3d array by splitting based on `#`.

```
def input = '''123456789#987465321,7410258#9630
852014864#456486454,5454646#4454''';

input=input.split('\n').collect{it.split(',')}
```

I tried to split like below code, But I'm getting exception. Is there any way using closure or any other method where we can split dynamically iresspective of input dimension in groovy.

```
input=input.collect{it.split('#')};

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.split() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [#]
Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), sort(), init(), toList(), tail()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.split() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [#]
Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), sort(), init(), toList(), tail()
    at com.test.TextScript$_run_closure2.doCall(TextScript.groovy:10)
    at com.test.TextScript.run(TextScript.groovy:10)
```

SO, I wanted to create a method in groovy which will take input parameter and the splitting delimiter which will create multidemensional array dynamically.

Example:

```
    static def split(def input,def delimiter){
    .
    .
    .
    }

def input = '''123456789#987465321,7410258#9630
852014864#456486454,5454646#4454'''; 
def result1=split(input,'\n');
println result1//1d [123456789#987465321,7410258#9630, 852014864#456486454,5454646#4454]

def result2=split(result1,',');
println result2//2d [[123456789#987465321, 7410258#9630], [852014864#456486454, 5454646#4454]]

def result3=split(result2,'#');
println result3// three dimension[[[123456789],[987465321], [7410258],[9630]], [[852014864],[456486454], [5454646],[4454]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive function.  Pass in the initial
input, you want to split and a list of regexp.  In each step the next
split will be done with the regexp for the depth.  E.g.

```
def multiSplit(String input, List res) {
  def result = input.split(res.head())
  res.size()>1 ? result.collect{ multiSplit(it, res.tail()) } : result
}

println(multiSplit('''123456789#987465321,7410258#9630
852014864#456486454,5454646#4454''', ["\n", ",", "#"]))
// → [[[123456789, 987465321], [7410258, 9630]], [[852014864, 456486454], [5454646, 4454]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what format you want the data in. This will take you closer to a solution:

```
def input = '''123456789#987465321,7410258#9630
852014864#456486454,5454646#4454'''

input.readLines().each { line ->
    println line.split(/,|#/)
}
```

Prints:

```
[123456789, 987465321, 7410258, 9630]
[852014864, 456486454, 5454646, 4454]
```

If you want it in a data structure, consider a map:

```
Map m = [:]
input.readLines().each { line ->
    line.split(/,/).each { kv ->
        List pairs = kv.split(/#/)
        m.put(pairs[0], pairs[1])
    }
}

println m
```

Produces:

```
[123456789:987465321, 7410258:9630, 852014864:456486454, 5454646:4454]
```

EDIT:

After understanding your expected output better, I think this is close to what you want, if not it will help you develop what you want.

```
import java.util.Collections

List li = []
input.readLines().each { line ->
    line.split(/,/).each { kv ->
        li.add(kv)
        li.each {
            Collections.replaceAll(li, kv, []+kv.split(/#/))
        }
    }
}

println li
```

It outputs:

```
[[[123456789, 987465321]], [[7410258, 9630]], [[852014864, 456486454]], [[5454646, 4454]]]
```

You should be able to wrap it in a method and parameterise it yourself.

Comment: I wanted to split the string to a 2d,3d data based on the number of time the split is happening. The splitting parameter can be anything so, we can't take each line. I have to write a method which takes input data and splitting parameter and splits the data. Suppose the data is 1d it'll be converted to 2d, if data is 2d after splitting it'll be 3d.

Comment: @rahul please edit your question by adding a sample of the output/format/structure you expect for your example.

Comment: sorry i have updated can you check now, I wanted to know how I have to implement the method for the dynamic multi-dimension array part.